# Friendly Id Custom Slug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

I have a Post model

```
#post.rb   
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: [:slugged, :history]
```

I'm trying to customize the url for each post like so

```
#post.rb 
def slug_candidates
 "#tutorial-#{user.display_name}-#{title}"
end
```

Friendly id keeps generating UUID slugs while I'd like it to generate a comprehensive url

Typically I get \tutorial-john-49c9938b-ece5-4175-a4a4-0bb2b0f26a27
Instead of \tutorial-john-some-comprehensive-title

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I edited the response, sorry.
It seems friendly_id expects an array of slug candidates. As you can see [here](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id#what-changed-in-version-50)

please try this:

```
#post.rb 
def slug_candidates
  [ "#tutorial-#{user.display_name}-#{title}" ]
end
```

Comment: tested with this but only got \tutorial-john. Seems like the title doesn't get generated by friendly id

Answer (score 1):

Understood. The slug was generated before I saved the title. It was therefore generated with a nil title. I had to override the should_generate_new_friendly_id method

```
def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
  slug.blank? || title_changed?
end
```