# How do I let an AR validation happen before a module extension on my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-5, friendly-id

I am using FriendlyID, and it creates a slug based on some attributes of a record upon creation.

```
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name_and_school, use: :slugged

  def name_and_school
    "#{first_name} #{last_name} #{school.name}"
  end
```

I also have the following on my model:

```
  validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true
  validates_associated :school, presence: true
```

However, when I go to test this validation and submit a form with an empty value for `first_name, last_name and school`, I get the following error:

```
  Position Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "positions".* FROM "positions" WHERE 1=0
   (0.8ms)  BEGIN
   (0.6ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 51ms (ActiveRecord: 11.7ms)



NoMethodError - undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass:
  app/models/profile.rb:79:in `name_and_school'
  friendly_id (5.1.0) lib/friendly_id/slugged.rb:295:in `should_generate_new_friendly_id?'
  friendly_id (5.1.0) lib/friendly_id/slugged.rb:304:in `set_slug'
```

So what's clear is that it is hitting that `name_and_school` method, even before it hits ActiveRecord's validation checks.

If it hit the validation checks first, it wouldn't generate this error it would just reload the page with the respective errors.

So how do I fix this and make sure the FriendlyID slug is only generated if all validations pass?

**Edit 1**

So I tried insisting that `name_and_school` only returns a valid string if the values are present like so:

```
  def name_and_school
    "#{first_name} #{last_name} #{school.name}" if first_name.present? && last_name.present? && school.present?
  end
```

This now works for empty/invalid `first_name` and `last_name` attributes.

However, when I leave the school field blank, it now gives me this error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 31689ms (Searchkick: 9.5ms | ActiveRecord: 23.6ms)

NoMethodError - undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass:
  app/models/profile.rb:139:in `search_data'
  searchkick (1.4.0) lib/searchkick/index.rb:289:in `search_data'
  searchkick (1.4.0) lib/searchkick/index.rb:66:in `block in bulk_index'
  searchkick (1.4.0) lib/searchkick/index.rb:66:in `bulk_index'
  searchkick (1.4.0) lib/searchkick/index.rb:54:in `store'
  searchkick (1.4.0) lib/searchkick/logging.rb:28:in `block in store'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  searchkick (1.4.0) lib/searchkick/logging.rb:27:in `store'
  searchkick (1.4.0) lib/searchkick/index.rb:96:in `reindex_record'
  searchkick (1.4.0) lib/searchkick/model.rb:113:in `reindex'
  app/models/profile.rb:146:in `reindex_profile'
```

Which corresponds to this in my model:

```
after_commit :reindex_profile

  def search_data
    {
      name: name,
      bib_color: bib_color,
      height: height,
      weight: weight,
      player_type: player_type,
      school_name: school.name,
      age: age,
      position_name: positions.map(&:name)
    }
  end

  def reindex_profile
    reindex
  end
```

Once the new record is committed, it runs that callback -- which expects a valid `school` attribute.

So the `nil` value is still escaping the validates_associated check.

I even tried adding that same `if` statement to the `reindex_profile` method like so:

```
  def reindex_profile
    reindex if first_name.present? && last_name.present? && school.present? && bib_color.present? && player_type.present? && age.present?
  end
```

But that doesn't work either.

**Edit 2**

After try @codyeatworld's answer, we are making progress.

The issue now is that even though I am not getting those errors any more, the record is being created despite the `validates_associated :school, presence: true` not being true.

For instance, here is an example of the request:

```
Started POST "/profiles" for ::1 at 2016-11-13 16:32:19 -0500
Processing by ProfilesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"skJA+9NB3XhR/JLgQ==", "profile"=>{"avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fbf3b35d9a8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/0f/hgplttnd7d/T/RackMultipart20161113-16651-1wvdzdx.jpg>, @original_filename="Random-Image.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profile[avatar]\"; filename=\"Random-Image.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "first_name"=>"Random", "last_name"=>"Brown", "dob(3i)"=>"13", "dob(2i)"=>"11", "dob(1i)"=>"1986", "weight"=>"", "height"=>"", "bib_color"=>"", "player_type"=>"player", "position_ids"=>[""], "school_id"=>"", "grade"=>"", "tournament_ids"=>[""], "email"=>"", "cell_phone"=>"", "home_phone"=>"", "grades_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"subject"=>"", "result"=>"", "grade_type"=>"csec", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "transcripts_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"url_cache"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "achievements_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"body"=>"", "achievement_type"=>"academic", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "videos_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"vimeo_url"=>"", "official"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "articles_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"source"=>"", "title"=>"", "url"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Profile"}
  User Load (1.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Role Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 2]]
  Role Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'coach') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 2]]
  Role Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'player') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 2]]
   (1.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)) OR ((roles.name = 'coach') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 2]]
The "mime_type" Shrine metadata field will be set from the "Content-Type" request header, which might not hold the actual MIME type of the file. It is recommended to load the determine_mime_type plugin which determines MIME type from file content.
  Tournament Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "tournaments".* FROM "tournaments" WHERE 1=0
  Position Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "positions".* FROM "positions" WHERE 1=0
   (0.9ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (2.2ms)  INSERT INTO "profiles" ("first_name", "last_name", "dob", "bib_color", "created_at", "updated_at", "player_type", "grade", "home_phone", "cell_phone", "email", "avatar_data") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"  [["first_name", "Yashin"], ["last_name", "Brown"], ["dob", Thu, 13 Nov 1986], ["bib_color", ""], ["created_at", 2016-11-13 21:32:19 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-11-13 21:32:19 UTC], ["player_type", 0], ["grade", ""], ["home_phone", ""], ["cell_phone", ""], ["email", ""], ["avatar_data", "{\"id\":\"83d162a3d33bdc5d2527502e1d423ab3.jpg\",\"storage\":\"cache\",\"metadata\":{\"filename\":\"Random-Image.jpg\",\"size\":61798,\"mime_type\":\"image/jpeg\"}}"]]
  SQL (2.0ms)  INSERT INTO "transcripts" ("profile_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["profile_id", 30], ["created_at", 2016-11-13 21:32:19 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-11-13 21:32:19 UTC]]
  Profile Load (3.7ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 30], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (1.6ms)  COMMIT
   (0.9ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (2.6ms)  UPDATE "profiles" SET "updated_at" = $1, "avatar_data" = $2 WHERE "profiles"."id" = $3  [["updated_at", 2016-11-13 21:32:19 UTC], ["avatar_data", "{\"id\":\"ec63dcc18ed5d60aa7a6626550f9f9ea.jpg\",\"storage\":\"store\",\"metadata\":{\"filename\":\"Random-Image.jpg\",\"size\":61798,\"mime_type\":\"image/jpeg\"}}"], ["id", 30]]
   (1.3ms)  COMMIT
  Profile Store (311.8ms)  {"id":30}
  Profile Store (32.2ms)  {"id":30}
  Profile Store (26.7ms)  {"id":30}
  Profile Store (18.9ms)  {"id":30}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/profiles/30
Completed 302 Found in 530ms (Searchkick: 389.6ms | ActiveRecord: 32.2ms)
```

Notice that `"school_id"=>""`, also notice that the URL is now `profiles/30` (rather than the FriendlyID URL, which means the friendlyID slug didn't execute which is what I want).

Why is this record still being created despite my `validates_associated` call I have on the model?

Comment: Try removing `use: :slugged` ?

Comment: But then that won't generate the slug I want on valid records, no?

Comment: You're right, it's been awhile since I used friendly_id. This answer might explain why: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36478639/6742278 . I think you need to tell friendlyId to generate the slug only if the school is present.

Comment: @codyeatworld Part of that approach works. I updated the question to show what works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `should_generate_new_friendly_id` then.

```
def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
  first_name.present? && last_name.present? && school.present?
end
```

FriendlyId will only try to create a slug if these conditions are met.

I think the offending line in searchkick is the `school.name` attribute.

```
def search_data
  {
    name: name,
    bib_color: bib_color,
    height: height,
    weight: weight,
    player_type: player_type,
    # school_name: school.name,
    school_name: (school.present? ? school.name : nil),
    age: age,
    position_name: positions.map(&:name)
  }
end
```

I'm assuming that you want to validate the presence of `school`. The method `validates_associated` will run the validations for the `school` object/model. It doesn't check the presence of `school_id`.

```
validates :first_name, :last_name, :school_id, presence: true
# Remove validates_associated :school, presence: true
```

I think you can also omit `_id`:

```
belongs_to :school
validates :school, presence: true
```

Comment: Ok...this does the same thing as adding `if first_name.present? && ...` However, the issue I am running into is another module now -- searchkick -- doing the same thing as FriendlyID. Thoughts there? In other words, I tried your answer and I still get the error related to `school.name is nil`.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Hard to say without seeing more of the models/how it's tied together.

Comment: Ok you are getting there slowly but surely. You were missing the ternary operator, which I added -- and which worked, in the sense that it no longer throws the weird error. However, there is something even more bizarre that's happening. The record was created, even though `validates_associated :school, presence: true` wasn't valid. I am going to update the question with more details.

Comment: Ahhh perfect. Thanks bro. That's exactly what the issue was. Thanks much!

Comment: Hrmm.... `presence: true` doesn't work for me. I get this error on that line: `Unknown key: :presence. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :foreign_type, :dependent, :primary_key, :inverse_of, :required, :polymorphic, :touch, :counter_cache, :optional`

Comment: Sorry, that was wrong, fixed example with correct information. I knew there was a way without the `_id`.

Comment: The weird thing is when I read through this issue - https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18233 - it seems like in Rails 5 all `belongs_to` are required to be valid or present by default. But that doesn't seem to be the case with me.